# MathJax rendering bug

Tags: support, mathjax

In this formula:

$$\frac{1}{\binom{n}{1}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{n}}=？$$

The $\binom{n}{3}$ renders much larger than the other `\binom` expressions. If I change the 3 to a 2 it looks correct.

Screenshot:

[image]

Here's my browser version information:

- Google Chrome:    19.0.1084.46 (Official Build 135956)
- OS:   Linux
- WebKit:   536.5 (@116441)
- JavaScript:   V8 3.9.24.21

Comment: I get the same effect (OS X 10.6.8, FF 12.0) when I right click on the math and choose `SVG` under `Math Settings -> Math Renderer`. With `HTML-CSS` and `MathML` it looks fine. It has likely to do with the fact that the glyph of `3` larger than the ones of `1,2` and `n`.

Comment: I didn't know that one could right-click a formula, thanks!  I was using HTML_CSS; switching my renderer to SVG does not fix the problem. Screenshot on request.

Comment: I can reproduce on Debian linux, IceWeasel version 10.0.4. The chosen renderer is already HTML-CSS.

Comment: @t.b. While the MathML corrects the problem it **does not** look fine! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the digit; neither 1 nor 2 cause the problem, but switch it to 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 0 (in any denominator) and it looks similar; e.g., 
$$\frac{1}{\binom{n}{1}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{3}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{8}}=?$$

A workaround is to use `\smash` on the 3 (or any items that cause the issue), so force $\LaTeX$ to think the box with the 3 is "standard" size. Thus,

> `\frac{1}{\binom{n}{1}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{\smash{3}}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{n}}=?`

produces
$$\frac{1}{\binom{n}{1}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{\smash{3}}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\binom{n}{n}}=?$$

Note that the problem is not related to the denominators, but rather to the rendering of the binomial coefficient when not in displaymode. For example, `$\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2}\binom{n}{3}\binom{n}{4}\binom{n}{5}\binom{n}{6}\binom{n}{7}\binom{n}{8}\binom{n}{9}\binom{n}{0}$` gives

$\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2}\binom{n}{3}\binom{n}{4}\binom{n}{5}\binom{n}{6}\binom{n}{7}\binom{n}{8}\binom{n}{9}\binom{n}{0}$

Comment: Thanks. I seem to remember that DEK guaranteed that all digit symbols would be the same height, to avoid problems like this. I don't know how MathJax chooses box heights. Do you suppose it ought to enforce a similar rule?

Comment: @Mark What's DEK? Just curious.

Comment: [Donald E. Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth), inventor of $\TeX$.

Comment: I was remembering wrong anyway; the digits *usually* not always) have the same *width*.  Of course they often don't have the same height; [for example](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Mediaevalziffern.svg).